# SVN submit db\transactions\106-43.txn\props The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: svn

While submitting my changes this error popped up from AnkSvn:

```
SharpSvn.SvnException: Commit failed (details follow): ---> SharpSvn.SvnException: Can't open file '\\dfs.coteng.com\coteng\cotengitbright\visualsvn\repositories\Coteng.DSAutomation\db\transactions\106-43.txn\props': The system cannot find the file specified.  
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at SharpSvn.SvnClientArgs.HandleResult(SvnClientContext client, SvnException error)
   at SharpSvn.SvnClientArgs.HandleResult(SvnClientContext client, svn_error_t* error)
   at SharpSvn.SvnClient.Commit(ICollection`1 paths, SvnCommitArgs args, SvnCommitResult& result)
   at Ankh.Services.PendingChanges.PendingChangeHandler.<>c__DisplayClass15.<Commit_CommitToRepository>b__14(Object sender, ProgressWorkerArgs e)
   at Ankh.ProgressRunnerService.ProgressRunner.Run(Object arg)
```

A similar message is shown when trying to submit with TortoiseSVN.
What does this props file do and does anybody know the possible root cause for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect that the `props` file is related to the revision properties for the commit (called a transaction at this stage, or `txn`).
Are you accessing a local repository, or is it remote?

It looks to me like something is going wrong on the server (or repository) side of this while it's creating the new commit.  Maybe a disk filled up, or permissions are wrong, or filesystem corruption... don't really know.

Can you provide any additional context?

Comment: I've looked into it with the sysadmin and it appears that our SVN repos are on a DFS system. Whenever the commit takes longer then "x" seconds the DFS starts replicating it to the other servers.
We think it is taking a lock on the directory and by that disallowing the SVN server to access it.
The reason they chose to put it on DFS is so our department abroad could use it too. I explained them that it won't work that way and that we will need a distributed source control system for that. Seen that it took me 2 years to convince them we need SC, I don't think this is a good thing.

Comment: If you have two people in different offices doing a commit at the same time, and the filesystem is getting updated out from under svn, I could see one side completing, deleting the temporary transaction files, and leaving the other side terribly confused.

Answer (score 1):

I just met the same error.

This was because the folders "txn-protorevs" and "transactions" of the "db" folder of my repository (on server side) were missing after a repository restoration from backup.

These folders are empty (unless during a commit) but they are mandatory so if your repository lacks them, you can restore these (just create as empty, with appropriate R/W rights).

Strangely, I also had to restart my SVN service to completely fix the issue. The commit succeeded, but after it I met some other errors, especially an "unexpected end of file" on last revision id while updating my working copy from a client computer.